# Trouble with drawing a moving paddle for pong flawlessly using Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, this

I am trying to make Pong. I sent this program to a friend and when he ran it the first time he got my bug but later it ran fine. I always seem to get the bug. My paddle can move up and down. It seems to move correctly and it gets drawn in the right place but it always flickers to the start position and back again. It looks like it gets drawn once at the start position and then at the right positions, flickering between the 2 positions forever.

NetBeans complains about this.addKeyListener(this);. It says "Leaking this in constructor". Here is my code: (sorry in advance, first time posting)

I exported it from netbeans if anyone wants to take a look:
http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=00856291054786890080

```
public class LeikGluggi extends javax.swing.JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Spilari1 spilari1 = new Spilari1();//make paddle
    Bolti bolti = new Bolti(); //make ball

    public LeikGluggi() {
        initComponents();
        setSize(Leikbord.GLUGGI_BREIDD,Leikbord.GLUGGI_HAED);
        this.addKeyListener(this); 
        this.setFocusable(true); 
        int i = 0;
        Timer tim = new Timer(50, this);
        tim.start();

    }
    private void uppfaera()//update
    {
        spilari1.uppfaera();//paddle update
        bolti.uppfaera(); // ball update

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g)
    {
        super.paintComponent(g);//
        g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g.fillRect(0,0,Leikbord.GLUGGI_BREIDD,Leikbord.GLUGGI_HAED); //background



        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        spilari1.paint(g);      //paddle drawn
        bolti.paint(g);         //ball drawn


    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {

        uppfaera();//update called

        repaint(); 

    }   

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e)
    {
       if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            spilari1.setyHradi(-4);
        }
        else if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            spilari1.setyHradi(4);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
        {
            spilari1.setyHradi(0);
        }
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)
        {
            spilari1.setyHradi(0);
        }
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e)
    {
    }
```

And the code for my paddle
package is.hi.vidmotsforritun.pong2.teikning;

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class Spilari1 {

    private final int breidd = 10 ;
    private final int lengd = 75;
    private int y = (Leikbord.GLUGGI_HAED/2)-lengd/2;
    private int yHradi = 0;


    public Spilari1()
    {
    }

    public void uppfaera()
    {
        y = y + yHradi;
        System.out.println("HRAÐI ER "+yHradi);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.fillRect(25, y, breidd, lengd);
        System.out.println("Y er "+y);

    }
        public void setyHradi(int hradi)
    {
        yHradi = hradi;
    }



}
```

Comment: It's a warning, which tells you that the object been passed (to key listener in this case) may not be fully invalided and could cause issues if the object (key listener) tries to access properties of "this" object before the constructor has completed. In this particular case, it should be an issue

Comment: I managed to fix my program by chaining y in the paddle window to public static in from being a private int. I have no idea why it fixed my problem but it did... I am still worried about the listener issue, any idea how I could set them up differently?

Answer (score 0):

According to this Thread ("http://forums.netbeans.org/post-134877.html") the problem is that you pass a reference of this to an outside class while not fully initialized (in constructor). So you need to do this later in an initialization method

Comment: Do you know hat is the best way to separate the Time and the actionlistener if the case is that they are conflicting?

Comment: Maybe use a method like init() where you put the actionlistener line in, and call that from outside after you called the constructor. Like LeikGluggi l = new LeikGluggi; l.init();